# Passing Value in 3 activities in Main activity

Tags: android

I have 3 buttons in main activity, this 3 buttons opens another activity, it is easy, medium and hard game type. i want to get the scores of each level of difficulties and store it in main activity, any example for this one? any help would greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to pass variable you want to share to the main activity in the Intent you're using to start the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", variable); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Access that intent on next activity

```
String variable= getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

The docs for Intents has more information (look at the section titled "Extras").

You can store variable to any variable you want in MainActivity and use it.

Comment: If works. Kindly tick mark the answer you have opt for.

Comment: You can alternately use SharedPreferences also. See my answer for details on how to use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Util` `Class`, in that `Class` create a `static` variable named `difficulty`.

Assign it according to `Button` pressed.

Inside `OnClickListener` assign it, later retrieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting values in Preference:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 
MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putInt("begginer", 120);  // put begginer level score here
 editor.putInt("medium", 37);  // put the medium level score here
 editor.putInt("hard", 12);  // put hard level score here
 editor.apply();
```

To Retrieve data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
  int begginer_score = prefs.getInt("begginer", 0); //0 is the default value.
  int medium_score = prefs.getInt("medium", 0); //0 is the default value.
  int hard_score = prefs.getInt("hard", 0); //0 is the default value.
```